# Is there a way to get a cell value from the selected row in DBGrid? (Delphi)

Tags: delphi, pascal

First of all, I'm pretty new to Delphi.

I have a `DBGrid` connected to a `DataSource` and filled up with data from an SQL server. What I want to achieve is that when I press a button, it brings up a new window with comboboxes/editboxes, all filled up with the previously selected (in `DBGrid`) row's data and modify them and execute an `UPDATE` query.

In order to do that, I need the primary key value of the selected record, so my little program would know which row should it display and update.

My question is, how can I get a specific cell value (in this case, an id) of a selected record from a `DBGrid`?

Comment: You can link extra DBEdits, DBComboBoxes and so on to the data source of your DBGrid. These will then be filled with the data of the selected row automatically!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the column for the ID field you can inspect its `Field` property. The Fields `Value` will contain the current ID.

Comment: Just wondering... how could I get the value of a row thet is NOT the current record? eg for multiselects and alike? I can imagine selecting multiple rows and then opeing muliple single record editors....

Comment: TDBGrid has a property `SelectedRows` holding a bookmark list of the selected records.

Comment: share a example please